# Can someone explain the loops?

Tags: python, function, loops, url, conditional-statements

I need help understanding this code. I can not make sense of the loops. Can someone please break it down and explain? What does "i=0" represents in this Program. I also have to add error handling for missing and invalid data. I would very much appreciate it. 
        Thank you!

```
        i = 0
        while i < len(line):

            if line[i] == '<':
                i = i + 1
                while i < len(line) and line[i] != '>':
                    tag += line[i]
                    i = i + 1

                if tag not in fields:
                    break;

                i = i + 1;

            while i < len(line) and line[i] != '<':

                value += line[i]
                i = i + 1
            break;
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: I am just looking for a explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Hi trying to answer as best as possible:
Very simple spoken:
While loop 0 checks for the end of the line
While loop 1 checks for the end of the tag (or line)
While loop 2 checks for the end of the value (or line)

**More detailed:**

```
i = 0
```

**[WHILE LOOP 0]**
i=0 is the start of the line and the while loop loops until *i* has reached the length of the line to check if the line has still content.

```
while i < len(line):
```

The if clause checks if an html tag opens.

```
if line[i] == '<':
    i = i + 1
```

**[WHILE LOOP 1]**
If so it adds 1 to i and runs an other while loop until the tag closes *(>)* or the end of the line is reached.

```
while i < len(line) and line[i] != '>':
    tag += line[i]
    i = i + 1
```

If the tag is not int the fields list from above it breaks the **While-Loop 0**

```
if tag not in fields:
    break;
```

This +1 is added when the while loop was successful and the tag is over, to go to the next character in the line

```
i = i + 1
```

**[WHILE LOOP 2]**
Then it goes to the next char and assumes that there a ***value*** coming.
The while loop loops until it finds again an html tag start. '<' Or the line is at the end.

```
while i < len(line) and line[i] != '<':
    value += line[i]
    i = i + 1
```

Then it breaks the outer **while loop 0**.

```
break
```

Happy about feedback and improvements of my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I can explain a little bit of this.

```
 I = 0
```

This is creating a new variable, called I, and setting it to zero.

```
while I < Len (line)
```

All this means is whatever code is executed in this loop will keep on executing until I is greater than how many lines there are. As you can see, in the loop, it adds 1 to i. This means that it will be a few seconds until the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some comments in the code which hopefully will make it easier to understand.
When adding error handling for missing or invalid data you  should look for places where you might need some data that is not available.

What happens if `data = ur.urlopen(link)` does not return any data? Can `urlopen` throw any exceptions? You can find this information in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

Once you know  about possible exceptions, you can catch them using a `try/except` block. For example:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError  # Exception happens here.
except ValueError:  # You catch it here.
   print("Cought a Value Error.")  # And handle it here.
```

```
    i = 0  # This seems to be a index for each character in a line. 0 is the first character in the line.
    while i < len(line):  # Loop until the index reaches the last character in the line.
        # If you find the < character at position i.
        if line[i] == '<':
            i = i + 1  
            while i < len(line) and line[i] != '>':  # Loop until you find the matching >.
                tag += line[i]  # Save all character in between < and >
                i = i + 1

            if tag not in fields:  # Didn't find what you where looking for so exit the while loop.
                break;

            i = i + 1;
        # You are still in the line but the current character is not <.
        while i < len(line) and line[i] != '<':
            # Save all characters until the line ends or you find a <.
            value += line[i]  
            i = i + 1
        break;  # Exit the while loop.
```